# Ubuntu Server OS drive out of space after running rsync between two drives

Tags: ubuntu

I have an ubuntu server which yesterday i performed an rsync command for the first time to backup a drive sdb1 to sdc1. Neither of these drives are the OS drive thats full.

This morning i woke up and the OS drive is full. I can't even boot into the GUI but i can still ssh into the machine.

any thoughts?

edit: I found the source - the rSync command seemed to be creating a directory /media/sdc1 physically on the OS drive instead of using the mounted /media/sdc1.

Does this command look right to you:

```
rsync -av --delete /media/sdb1 /media/sdc1
```

Drive 1 is mounted sdb1 and drive 2 is sdc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find what is filling your OS drive by using the command

du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -rn

which will give you a list of files/directories and their sizes. You can then work your way down the file system to find which file(s) are filling the disk.

Comment: Found the source, please see my original post

Comment: @KP65: show us the output of `df`